# How to pass empty variables in function and change their values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to pass a string that contains empty values and after fill them in the function. (I know SQL injection). On the other hand I would like to have a good example with pdo statement

```
function foo(&$var) {
    $variable1="test";
    $variable2="test";
    echo $var;
}
$string="UPDATE table SET column1=$variable1 WHERE column2=$variable2";
foo($string);
```

I also know another method to achieve this. But it insn't a good way

```
function test($Query) {
        $variable1="test";
        $variable2="test";

        $finalQuery = vsprintf($Query, array($variable1, $variable2));
        print_r($finalQuery);
    }
$Query = "UPDATE table SET column1='%s' WHERE column2='%s'";
test($Query);
```

Comment: Can you give us a proper example of what you're trying to do? The code you've posted doesn't really make sense. You're just creating local variables in the function that you don't do anything with and you're not returning anything. With a proper example, we will have a better understanding.

Comment: If this isn't just an example and you're actually looking for something to use to execute SQL, you should definitely use a prepared statement instead of a variable replacement/interpolation function.

Comment: why not put the query string in the function? why not use pdo, seems like your making this way harder than it needs to be

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I would simply like to get what I get with the test function (second function that i posted, which works) but in a better way (pdo statment for example)

Comment: @IdontDownVote because i have more submit buttons that contains different queries

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still have no clue what problem you're trying to solve. You're simply just outputting some values in your function. I don't know how that would relate to any "pdo statement"? Also, _"I would like to pass a string that contains empty values"_ doesn't make sense. A string is a string. It's _one_ value (or an empty string), not several values. If you want to pass in an "empty value", why even pass anything at all?

Comment: are the variables really hard codded in the function? so only the query changes? (its usually the other way around)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no i have 1 string out of function ($Query) that contains 2 empty variables ($variable1 and $variable2)! I need to correctly fill $Query with values that i'll create in the function

Comment: @IdontDownVote I have something like that https://pastebin.com/cw3m4Ei8. Afterwards, within the function, I would like to fill in the respective $ queries

Comment: In your example, the function is pretty useless. You don't need it in a function since you're just setting `$variable1` and `$variable2` in the function as well. You really need to take a step back, look at your question and then rewrite it. It's  still super unclear what you want. The phrase "a string with two empty variables" makes no sense at all.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please look again at the pastebin (i know that submit3 doesn't work actually)

Comment: I don't go off-site to look at code. You should include all relevant code into the question itself.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is only an example! the relevant example is the second function that i posted!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `$variable1` and `$variable2` aren't defined literally as shown in your example, (I'm assuming this from your comment "I need to correctly fill $Query with values that i'll create in the function") I would say your function needs to take a prepared statement instead of a string.

```
function foo(PDOStatement $statement) {
    // stuff happens that creates $variable1 and $variable2
    $statement->bindValue(1, $variable1);
    $statement->bindValue(2, $variable2);
    return $statement;
}
```

And instead of defining `$string`, create a prepared statement and pass that to the function.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET column1=? WHERE column2=?');
foo($statement);
```

---

As far as the way you're trying to do it in the first code block in your question, there are a few problems.

The only way to pass a string with predefined variables in it and then fill those in the function is to define the string with single quotes first. Otherwise, with double quotes, PHP will look for `$variable1` and `$variable2` in the global scope, not find them, and their undefined (null) values will be replaced with empty strings in `$string` before you can pass to the function.

```
$string='UPDATE table SET column1=$variable1 WHERE column2=$variable2';
```

Then, in the function, the only way I know of that you'd be able to get those predefined variables interpolated is by passing that string to `eval`.

```
function foo(&$var) {
    $variable1="test";
    $variable2="test";
    eval('$var = "' . $var . '";');
    echo $var;
}
```

Now, this works for this example, but ***it is a terrible idea***.

- When you write the string like that, you're depending on certain variables being defined inside the function, and your function depends on its input having those variables. You'll never be able to change that function.
- It depends on `eval`. Using eval is dangerous; it allows any string to be executed on your system as PHP code, and you probably won't be able to safely limit the source of that string.
- If this is going to be used to execute SQL, this is not a good way to do that, regardless of whether or not it's a good way to build strings in general, which I've already said it isn't. You should be binding the values to a prepared statement.

Comment: An other way is to use VSPRINTF as i wrote before in my second function that i named "test". I know also "eval" , but as you say, it's a terrible idea!

Comment: Hi @stackss, I'm editing the answer to show a way to do what I think you're trying to do with a prepared statement.

Comment: where i can see this new way?

Comment: @stackss Sorry, hadn't finished editing yet. Check the part at the end of the answer.

Comment: It binds the values defined in the function to the prepared statement given as an argument. Is that not what you need it to do?

Comment: yes, you understood very well, but unfortunately it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it doesn't work? I feel like we're getting closer to a good solution.

Comment: I see. The thing is, that isn't how prepared statements work. You won't be able to see the SQL string with the values bound to it. The function takes the statement and binds the values, and if you call `$statement->execute()` after `foo($statement)`, the statement will be executed with the values you bound in the function.

Comment: Probably you are right but If i put `$statement->execute();` after `foo($statement);` i get a blank page!

Comment: `$statement->execute();` doesn't print anything, it executes the statement. You won't be able to see the query string with the bound values in it. That's kind of the point of parameterized statements - they separate the SQL from the values. The evidence that it works properly will be that the query was executed, if it wasn't you should get a PDOException.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysqli for this:

```
class Database {
  protected $con;
  public __construct(){
    $this->con=mysqli_connect("my_host","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }
  }

  public __destruct(){
    mysqli_close($this->con);
  }

  public query($sql){
    if (!mysqli_query($this->con,$sql)) {   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($this->con)); };
  }

}

class Table extends Database {
  public function update($var, $var2){
    $var = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$var);
    $var2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$var2);
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET column1=$var1 WHERE column2=$var2";
    $this->query($sql);
  }
}
```

This way, you can use php `mysqli_real_escape_string`, that will help you to prevent SQL injection.

Also, you can go by prepared statements option.
Just change, update method for:

```
public function update($var, $var2){
        $smtp = mysqli_prepare($this->con,"UPDATE table SET column1=? WHERE column2=?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($smtp,'ss', $var,$var2);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: I would rather say that you should use prepared statements over mysql_escape_string().

Comment: @FedeCaceres I don't want to put the query inside the function!

Comment: @FedeCaceres I repeat: I don't want to put the query inside the function! and I'd rather use PDO instead of mysqli

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to achieve this.

```
<?php
/* On update l'historique côté vets; ici on controle et on dit KESSKONFAI*/
    include('../Models/db_connect.php');
    $a = explode('-',$_GET['a']);
    $o = $_GET['o'];

    switch($a):
        case($a[1] === 'breed'):
                if($a[0] === 'desc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY breed DESC";
                } else if ($a[0] === 'asc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY breed ASC";
                }
            break;
        case($a[1] === 'name'):
                if($a[0] === 'desc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY pet_name DESC";
                } else if ($a[0] === 'asc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY pet_name ASC";
                }
            break;
        case($a[1] === 'color'):
                if($a[0] === 'desc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY colour DESC";
                } else if ($a[0] === 'asc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY colour ASC";
                }
            break;
        case($a[1] === 'sex'):
                if($a[0] === 'desc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY sex DESC";
                } else if ($a[0] === 'asc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY sex ASC";
                }
                break;
        case($a[1] === 'date'):
                if($a[0] === 'desc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY date_of_birth DESC";
                } else if ($a[0] === 'asc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY date_of_birth ASC";
                }
            break;
        case($a[1] === 'chip'):
                if($a[0] === 'desc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY microchip_tatoo DESC";
                } else if ($a[0] === 'asc'){
                    $query = 
                    "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                    FROM patients
                    WHERE
                    owner_ID = :ID
                    ORDER BY microchip_tatoo ASC";
                }
            break;
        case($a[1] === 'hist'):
            if($a[0] === 'desc'){
                $query = 
                "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                FROM patients
                WHERE
                owner_ID = :ID
                ORDER BY history DESC";
            } else if ($a[0] === 'asc'){
                $query = 
                "SELECT pet_name, ID, breed, colour, sex, date_of_birth,microchip_tatoo, history
                FROM patients
                WHERE
                owner_ID = :ID
                ORDER BY history ASC";
            }
            break;
        default:
    endswitch;

    if(isset($query)){
        include('../Models/order_by_clients.php');
        $patients_rows = order_by($query,$o,$db);
    }
?>
```

Function :

```
<?php
    function order_by($query,$o,&$db){

        $query_params = array(':ID' => $o);

            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                $patients_rows = $stmt -> fetchAll();
                for($i = 0;$i < count($patients_rows);$i++){
                    $patients_rows[$i]['history'] = "\n".strtr($patients_rows[$i]['history'],array("."=>".\r\r","\S:"=>" :\r","-"=>" - "));
                }
                include '../Views/order_by_clients.php';

            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
            }
    }
?>
```

But with the switch in the function